# Hilbert Triplet

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let **H**, **V** be two Hilbert spaces.
Let $ \textbf{V} \hookrightarrow \textbf{H} $ and let $\textbf{V}$ dense in $\textbf{H}$.
Then, the Hilbert triplet theorem holds, and we can write 
$ \textbf{V} \hookrightarrow \textbf{H} \hookrightarrow \textbf{V'} $, where $ \textbf{V'}$ is the dual of $ \textbf{V}$.

My question is the following: since Riesz lemma and since **H** and **V** Hilbert spaces, I can identify **H** with **H'** (where **H'** is the dual of **H**), but why I can't apply the Riesz lemma to **V** and identify it to its dual **V'**?
I mean.. That would be absurd - having supposed that the norm of **H** and **V** are not necessarily equivalent. Why I can't apply Riesz lemma to **V**?

Answer (score 4):

Let me denote the embeddings $V\hookrightarrow H$ and $H\hookrightarrow V'$ by $i$ and $i'$. Then $i(V)$ and $i'(H)$ are dense in $H$ and $V'$. So the Hilbert triple method yields a mapping $ii': V \to V'$ with dense range. In many examples $i$ and thus $i'$ are compact, so $ii'$ is not continuously invertible.

By Riesz theorem you get another mapping  $I: V \to V'$ which is an isomorphism.

However, $ii' \ne I$, which can be easily seen in the compact case.

Note that both methods give different constructions to get from $V$ to $V'$: The Hilbert triple uses the inner product in $H$, the Riesz theorem the inner product in $V$.

So you still can apply Riesz theorem. It is however not advised to do so, as it bears the danger to silently make use of the faulty identification $I=ii'$.

Comment: What do you mean with "it's not advised to do so"? Does it mean that I can do it if and only if $I = ii'$?

Comment: You can still work with $I$ and $ii'$ at the same time, as long as you do keep track of them. I would advise not to use both things at the same time, as this is really error-prone as the identification $I=ii'$ is soooo tempting. I fell into this trap at lest once :) And my experience is that one never has to work with $I$ and $ii'$ at the same time. Ususally the Hilbert triple stuff is enough. Adding Riesz into the picture does not lead to anything new besides errors, in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks, you have been kind and exhaustive :D