# Is a dense subspace of a Hilbert space not a Hilbert space in itself?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I am asking this because I'm trying to wrap my head around rigged Hilbert spaces (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigged_Hilbert_space#Formal_definition_(Gelfand_triple) ). In RHS theory, it is usually talked about a triplet ($\phi$, $H$, $\phi^*$), where $H$ is an infinite dimentional Hilbert space, $\phi\subset H$ is dense and $\phi^*$ is its dual. In this context, one has the following relation:

$$\phi\subset H=H^*\subset \phi^*\,,$$

which implies that $\phi$ is not itself a Hilbert space as a Hilbert space and its dual should de isomorphic (and since it can be associated to the same scalar product as H, it would further mean that $\phi$ is actually not complete).

My question would be: is this always the case (i.e. any dense subset of a Hilbert space is not complete) or it just happens in certain cases?

My atempt at explaining why it is always the case is: Since all infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces are isomorphic to an $l^2$ space, $\phi$ being a Hilbert space implies that $\phi$ is isomorpric to H, which contadicts the proper subset statement. Does this make sense?

Comment: **Hint :** complete $\Longrightarrow$ closed.

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2690514/hilbert-triplet?rq=1 does this answer your question?

Comment: Just a small thing: "Since all infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces are isomorphic to $\ell^2$", that should be "all infinite dimensional separable Hilbert spaces"

Comment: Perhaps [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/740355/dual-of-h1-0-h-1-or-h-01) too may clarify the point.