Ries representation VS nested hilbert spaces
Consider 2 hilbert spaces V ↪H , V continus dens included in H ,V≠H and the duals H* and V* . As far as the proofs I understand why we sey V↪H=H* ↪V*, but I fail to understand why this example does not contradict the ries representation theorem. By ries we have H=H* and V=V* , but this implies V=H contradicting so when can we use V=V* and when not.

$H=H^{*}$ is not a set theoretic equality.

You say $V\hookrightarrow H=H^\hookrightarrow V^$. This is not true. The adjoint of an inclusion operator need not be an inclusion operator.

See this post https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2690514/136544

@daw God bless you !
